# Determining Whether or not a complex graph is bipartition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, bipartite-graphs

So I asked a question earlier similar to this, and the solution made sense; however, the graph was very simple with only five vertices. If the graph is more complex like this one [image: Graph] then how would you determine if the graph is a bipartite? When I asked earlier, I was shown the method of trying different color combinations for all the vertices, and checking if the edges connected opposite vertices that way, but is there another way to do it for a more complex graph like this one?

Comment: This particular graph contains a cycle of odd length, so it is not bipartite.

Comment: Can you explain that to me? I missed this class, so I have no idea what I'm looking at exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The general procedure is to start giving alternative colors to each connected node of the graph.